# Bash Command Substitution Giving Weird Inconsistent Output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For some reasons not relevant to this question, I am running a Java server in a bash script not directly but via command substitution under a separate sub-shell, and in the background. The intent is for the subcommand to return the process id of the Java server as its standard output. The fragement in question is as follows:

```
launch_daemon()
{
  /bin/bash <<EOF
     $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $JAR_FILE daemon $PWD/config/cl.yml <&- &
     pid=\$!
     echo \${pid} > $PID_FILE
     echo \${pid}   
EOF
}

daemon_pid=$(launch_daemon)

echo ${daemon_pid} > check.out
```

The Java daemon in question prints to standard error and quits if there is a problem in initialization, otherwise it closes standard out and standard err and continues on its way. Later in the script (not shown) I do a check to make sure the server process is running. Now on to the problem.

Whenever I check the $PID_FILE above, it contains the correct process id on one line.

But when I check the file check.out, it sometimes contains the correct id, other times it contains the process id repeated twice on the same line separated by a space charcater as in:

```
34056 34056
```

I am using the variable $daemon_pid in the script above later on in the script to check if the server is running, so if it contains the pid repeated twice this totally throws off the test and it incorrectly thinks the server is not running. Fiddling with the script on my server box running CentOS Linux by putting in more echo statements etc. seems to flip the behavior back to the correct one of $daemon_pid containing the process id just once, but if I think that has fixed it and check in this script to my source code repo and do a build and deploy again, I start seeing the same bad behavior.

For now I have fixed this by assuming that $daemon_pid could be bad and passing it through awk as follows:

```
mypid=$(echo ${daemon_pid} | awk '{ gsub(" +.*",""); print $0 }')
```

Then $mypid always contains the correct process id and things are fine, but needless to say I'd like to understand why it behaves the way it does. And before you ask, I have looked and looked but the Java server in question does NOT print its process id to its standard out before closing standard out.

Would really appreciate expert input.

Comment: How are you guarding against concurrent runs? Perhaps upstart is executing your script too?

Comment: Good question, it is not really protected against that. The build and deploy is via our own Jenkins box and the server is our own, so we're in control so I'm pretty sure that's not happening. Plus I have seen the same behavior, though not always and not consistently, when running the start.sh script that contains the above fragment directly from the command line on the box being deployed to.

Comment: Also, we're not running via upstart as a standard daemon. We have an ansible playbook based process for deployment and running that just runs the start.sh script. In a previous step in the ansible playbook, it kills any existing running daemon.

Comment: Is there any service monitoring. If so, it might kick off another one concurrently. Obviously I'm just trying to rule something out rather then answering.

Comment: There is monitoring, but at least currently there is no automatic restart. We're just at the beginning of the project so we might add that later but right now that's not an issue. Plus the repeated process id is the same, with a restart or concurrent running issue you'd think they would be two different pid's, although the mechanism would still have to be explained.

Comment: I'm a little leery of <&- in context.

Comment: I can't see any way you could get a repeated pid like that unless the java daemon is printing it. You say you've checked that by code inspection; have you tried adding `>/dev/null` to the java line to make absolutely sure?

Comment: I got that from some blog post while cobbling this together, to my understanding that closes standard input for the Java daemon. I'm not sure now that is really required but why would it be hurting? The Java daemon is not reading from standard input anyway, I'm guessing if it were to attempt that at some point it would throw an exception for trying to read from a closed file. But I'm not seeing that.

Comment: @rici it's not just code inspection, I have run the same daemon many times from the command line directly on the same box, it only prints to standard error if it has an initialization error and then quits, if no error it doesn't print anything to standard out or standard error, closes them both and continues running. Of course it continues logging to a file based on its configuration, but standard out and standard error are closed.

Comment: @rici but still a useful suggestion, I will try that just to make 100% sure.

Comment: Programs are entitled to have a standard input that's open. If you want it to be harmless, redirect it from `/dev/null`, rather than closing it.  Similarly for unwanted standard output and standard error (though I recommend against throwing away error messages).

Comment: @user2456600: there is certainly a race condition in your launch_daemon function, since if the `/bin/bash` terminates before your java server manages to detach itself, then the java server will be killed. That wouldn't result in a duplicated pid, though; it would result in a meaningless pid. Anyway, I believe you've tested it, but I don't see that it would hurt to try adding `>/dev/null` and verify.

Comment: @Jonathan But this is a daemon process that does NOT read anything from standard in, or write to standard out or error once successfully initialized. So I'm doing those on purpose, and like I said the daemon process is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @rici good point hadn't thought of that race condition. That doesn't really seem to be the issue though. I'm wondering if it is bash printing the pid of the Java daemon being run in the background. For example if I run "ls &" bash prints the pid before the ls output.

Comment: I stand by 'standard I/O channels should be open'.  However, it probably isn't the cause of the trouble you're seeing.  My best guess is that PID_FILE is not always set; you might get the double PID in `daemon_pid` when it is not set. I emphasize 'guess'; we can't see enough code to know whether that could happen, or how that could happen.

Comment: @Jonathan earlier in the script, before the definition of launch_daemon I have "PID_FILE=web_api.PID". In any case, like I said that web_api.PID file always exists and has the right contents. It's the variable $daemon_pid that has the repeated value.

Comment: Yes; so my guess is that somehow the `launch_daemon` function is echoing the PID twice. I'm not convinced that $PID_FILE unset is relevant; it gives a syntax error — consider that withdrawn. Is there any danger that the `bash` inside the function could be echoing the PID of the background process automatically? Seems a little unlikely, but we're all clutching at straws here. Have you run the code with `set -x` sprinkled around liberally, so you can see what `bash` thinks it is doing? You'll probably need a `set -x` in the function, and also in the script that's run by `bash` from the function.

Comment: @user2456600: bash doesn't print that message unless it's interactive, and it doesn't consider itself interactive if stdin is redirected (as with `<<EOF`) unless you specify `-i`. Anyway, if it does print that message, it goes to `stderr` afaik. But it's still a possibility.

Comment: @rici I copied this scheme from http://barelyenough.org/blog/2005/03/java-daemon/ (not all the way though) which claims that a shell won't exit while it has programs attached to its standard out and standard err, so wouldn't that mean there is no race condition? In any  =case I am in the middle of trying your suggestion because I guess standard err is not being redirected so if that blog post is true that would still serve the purpose of avoid that race condition. Trying your suggestion takes some time though because I want to do it properly all the way through Jenkins and ansible deployment.

Comment: @rici redirecting standard out /dev/null in line running the Java daemon didn't fix it :-( Still get the process id double printed in the check.out file (which comes from $daemon_pid) but fine in web_api.PID (which comes directly from $pid in the launch_daemon function)

Comment: @user2456600: I don't believe the claim about a shell not exiting. It's easy enough to test. (An interactive shell will ask for verification about exiting while there are unterminated jobs. But that's quite different.)

Comment: The same behavior is observed when java is replaced with a simple script that does nothing, so the java is irrelevant.  I suspect this is a bug in bash, related to the sub-bash not flushing an output stream, but I cannot see the details yet.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Good point, and a very helpful observation. But I'm pretty sure it's a race condition, not a failure to flush. See my answer for the gories.

Comment: As an aside, the Awk hack is needlessly complicated. `${daemon_pid%% *}` will expand to the value with anything after the first space trimmed.

Comment: Thanks @triplee for increasing my bash/awk fu

Answer (score 4):

Following the hint by @WilliamPursell, I tracked this down in the bash source code. I honestly don't know whether it is a bug or not; all I can say is that it seems like an unfortunate interaction with a questionable use case.

**TL;DR: You can fix the problem by removing `<&-` from the script.**

Closing `stdin` is at best questionable, not just for the reason mentioned by @JonathanLeffler ("Programs are entitled to have a standard input that's open.") but more importantly because `stdin` is being used by the `bash` process itself and closing it in the background causes a race condition.

In order to see what's going on, consider the following rather odd script, which might be called Duff's Bash Device, except that I'm not sure that even Duff would approve: (also, as presented, it's not that useful. But someone somewhere has used it in some hack. Or, if not, they will now that they see it.)

```
/bin/bash <<EOF
if (($1<8)); then head -n-$1 > /dev/null; fi
echo eight
echo seven
echo six
echo five
echo four
echo three
echo two
echo one
EOF
```

For this to work, `bash` and `head` both have to be prepared to share `stdin`, including sharing the file position. That means that `bash` needs to make sure that it flushes its read buffer (or not buffer), and `head` needs to make sure that it seeks back to the end of the part of the input which it uses.

(The hack only works because `bash` handles here-documents by copying them into a temporary file. If it used a pipe, it wouldn't be possible for `head` to seek backwards.)

Now, what would have happened if `head` had run in the background? The answer is, "just about anything is possible", because `bash` and `head` are racing to read from the same file descriptor. Running `head` in the background would be a really bad idea, even worse than the original hack which is at least predictable.

Now, let's go back to the actual program at hand, simplified to its essentials:

```
/bin/bash <<EOF
cmd <&- &
echo \$!
EOF
```

Line 2 of this program (`cmd <&- &`) forks off a separate process (to run in the background). In that process, it closes `stdin` and then invokes `cmd`.

Meanwhile, the foreground process continues reading commands from `stdin` (its `stdin` fd hasn't been closed, so that's fine), which causes it to execute the `echo` command.

Now here's the rub: `bash` knows that it needs to share `stdin`, so it can't just close `stdin`. It needs to make sure that `stdin`'s file position is pointing to the right place, even though it may have actually read ahead a buffer's worth of input. So just before it closes `stdin`, it seeks backwards to the end of the current command line. [1]

If that seek happens before the foreground bash executes `echo`, then there is no problem. And if it happens after the foreground bash is done with the here-document, also no problem. But what if it happens *while the echo is working*? In that case, after the `echo` is done, `bash` will reread the `echo` command because `stdin` has been rewound, and the `echo` will be executed again.

And that's precisely what is happening in the OP. Sometimes, the background seek completes at just the wrong time, and causes `echo \${pid}` to be executed twice. In fact, it also causes `echo \${pid} > $PID_FILE` to execute twice, but that line is idempotent; had it been `echo \${pid} >> $PID_FILE`, the double execution would have been visible.

So the solution is simple: remove `<&-` from the server start-up line, and optionally replace it with `</dev/null` if you want to make sure the server can't read from `stdin`.

---

**Notes:**

Note 1: For those more familiar with bash source code and its expected behaviour than I am, I believe that the seek and close takes place at the end of `case r_close_this:` in function `do_redirection_internal` in `redir.c`, at approximately line 1093:

```
check_bash_input (redirector);
close_buffered_fd (redirector);
```

The first call does the `lseek` and the second one does the `close`. I saw the behaviour using `strace -f` and then searched the code for a plausible looking `lseek`, but I didn't go to the trouble of verifying in a debugger.

Comment: Wow, for some reason I moved on after doing my workaround but was never notified of this answer. This is most comprehensive, thanks for digging so deep :-)

Comment: Now that I come back after some time to check my question picked up another useful tip on simplifying my awk hack too. I hang my head in shame.