# bash wrap a piped command with a python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, strace

Is there a way to create a python script which wraps an entire bash command including the pipes.

For example, if I have the following simple script

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

and call it like so (from bash or ipython), I get the expected outcome:

```
[pkerp@pendari trell]$ python test.py ls
['test.py', 'ls']
```

If I add a pipe, however, the output of the script gets redirected to the pipe sink:

```
[pkerp@pendari trell]$ python test.py ls > out.txt
```

And the `> out.txt` portion is not in sys.argv. I understand that the shell automatically process this output, but I'm curious if there's a way to force the shell to ignore it and pass it to the process being called.

The point of this is to create something like a wrapper for the shell. I'd like to run the commands regularly, but keep track of the strace output for each command (including the pipes). Ideally I'd like to keep all of the bash features, such as tab-completion and up and down arrows and history search, and then just pass the completed command through a python script which invokes a subprocess to handle it.

Is this possible, or would I have to write my own shell to do this?

**Edit**

It appears I'm asking the exact same thing as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525056/bash-or-other-shell-wrap-all-commands-with-function-script).

Comment: Terminology note: that's not a pipe, it's an output redirection.

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. The point still applies though. The problem remains the same if it wasn't a redirection but a pipe instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't quite see what you are trying to do. The general approach would be to give the desired output destination to the script using command line options: `python test.py ls --output=out.txt`. Incidentally, strace writes to stderr. You could capture everything using `strace python test.py > out 2> err` if you want to save everything...

Edit: If your script writes to stderr as well you could use `strace -o strace_out python test.py > script_out 2> script_err`

Edit2: Okay, I understand better what you want. My suggestion is this: Write a *bash* helper:

```
function process_and_evaluate()
{

  strace -o /tmp/output/strace_output "$@"

  /path/to/script.py /tmp/output/strace_output
}
```

Put this in a file like `~/helper.sh`. Then open a bash, source it using `. ~/helper.sh`.
Now you can run it like this: `process_and_evaluate ls -lA`.

Edit3:
To capture output / error you could extend the macro like this:

```
function process_and_evaluate()
{
  out=$1
  err=$2

  shift 2

  strace -o /tmp/output/strace_output "$@" > "$out" 2> "$err"

  /path/to/script.py /tmp/output/strace_output
}
```

You would have to use the (less obvious ) `process_and_evaluate out.txt err.txt ls -lA`.
This is the best that I can come up with...

Comment: Right, so imagine that I have a command `ls -l > ls_output.txt 2> ls_error.txt`. I'd like to run this command from the shell as usual, but in between when I hit enter, and execute the command, I'd like to call a python script which will wrap the command in a `strace` call and then process the output.

Comment: Also, your example wouldn't capture the file accesses generated by the redirection. One would have to run `strace -o bash -c "ls > ls_out 2> ls_err"', but that's beside the point. The reason I want it handled by a python script is to process the output of strace for each command.

Comment: The helper doesn't capture the redirection :(

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is pass the entire shell command as a string, then let Python pass it back to a shell for execution.

```
$ python test.py "ls > out.txt"
```

Inside `test.py`, something like

```
subprocess.call("strace " + sys.argv[1], shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

to ensure the entire string is passed to the shell (and `bash`, specifically).

Comment: There's really nothing I can change in the `.bashrc` that contains the text of the command I'm trying to run? It must be stored somewhere if it gets recorded in the history file.

Comment: As far as I know, `bash` simply does not have the level of introspection you are looking for.

Comment: Hmmm... would you happen to know of another shell that does?

Answer (score 0):

At least in your simple example, you could just run the python script as an argument to echo, e.g.

```
$ echo $(python test.py ls) > test.txt
$ more test.txt
['test.py','ls']
```

Enclosing a command in parenthesis with a dollar sign first executes the contents then passes the output as an argument to echo.